# How to integrate with respect to a variable that was substituted?

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, substitution

Take $P(x)=1000+\int_{0}^{x} M(s)ds$. If $x=5t$, how do I write an equation for the $P(x)$ as a function of $t$?

That is with the function being $P(t)$, not $P(5t)$. So how do I make $P(5t)=1000+\int_{0}^{t} M(s)ds$ into a $P(t)$ function?

Comment: I don't understand.  $P(x)$ is, in words, one thousand plus the integral of $M(s)$ from $s = 0$ to $x$.  So $P(5t)$ should be one thousand plus the integral of $M(s)$ from $s = 0$ to $5t$; that is, $P(5t) = 1000 + \int_{s=0}^{5t} M(s) \, ds$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I understand what $P(5t)$ should equal, that's just simple substitution. But how do I obtain the equation for P(t)?

Comment: I'm still having trouble figuring out what you're trying to obtain.  Why isn't $P(t)$ simply $1000+\int_{s = 0}^t M(s) \, ds$?  Are you trying to obtain $P(t)$ in terms of $P(5t)$?

Comment: I'm trying to obtain $P(t)$ in terms of just $t$. But currently all I have is $P(5t)$.

Comment: This is still unclear.  Why isn't the upper limit of your integral $5t$, rather than $t$?  What is unsatisfactory about my expression for $P(t)$ in my last comment?  If we can agree on that, maybe we can solve the problem.

Comment: In your last comment, you stated that $P(t)$ should just simple be $1000+\int_{0}^{t} M(s)ds$. But that is the $P(x)$ expression. They cannot be the same because $x=5t$. So right now I have the $P(5t)$ expression, the same as in your first comment. But how do I obtain the $P(t)$ expression, not $P(5t)$?

Comment: Our expressions are *not* the same.  I have $5t$ as the upper limit; you have $t$ as the upper limit.  Which do you think is correct? ¶ It does not follow that because $x = 5t$, it cannot be the case that $P(t)$ is the same thing as $P(x)$, but with $x$ replaced by $t$.  To take a simpler example, suppose $Q(x) = x+10$, and $x = 5t$.  That means that $Q(x) = 5t+10$, but it does not imply that $Q(t) \not= t+10$; in fact, I would say that it does imply that $Q(t) = t+10$.  $Q$ is simply a function that takes its argument and adds $10$ to it.

Comment: In the same way, $P(\cdot)$ is simply a function that takes the integral of $M(s)$ from $s = 0$ to whatever the argument of $P$ is, and adds $1000$ to it.  Doesn't that sound right?

Comment: Oh ok! I think I understand. I believe I made an error in fundamental math. When looking at the expression $x=5t$, inside $P(x)=1000+\int_{0}^{x} M(s)ds$, I not only replaced the upper limit of integration, but also within the $P(x)$ to make it $P(5t)$. I now see that $P(5t)=1000+\int_{0}^{5t} M(s)ds$ would be equal to $P(x)=1000+\int_{0}^{x} M(s)ds$. So to find P(t), I would not substitute $5t$ for $x$ in the $P(x)$, but only on the right side of the equation: $P(t)=1000+\int_{0}^{5t} M(s)ds$.